# Python: While and For loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Please help me in understanding why my code is not working as I want it to be. I cannot match the result when I run the code in my head vs the actual result in the console. It is very simple:

Given List "num_list", I want to take the odd numbers, sum them up and show the result, with the condition that it has to take and sum the first 5 odd numbers from the list.

i.e.

result= 85 + 719 + 85 + 17 + 191

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

result=0

odd_num=[]

count_odd=0

while count_odd < 5:
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        if num_list[i]%2!=0:
            odd_num.append(num_list[i])
            count_odd+=1 
            result+=sum(odd_num)


print(result)
```

The thing is that the while loop does not stop at `count_odd < 5`.

I am learning the very basics and I want to understand what is going on here.

Thank you

Comment: `result` is wrong.  This would be correct: `85 + 719 + 85 + 17 + 87`

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple things wrong with your current code and some things that are unessaccary.

Your while loop is not needed, because you use a `for range`.

You don't want to use a `for range` loop when iterating through a list

you can simply just append odd numbers to a list in you loop. Then outside of your loop find the sum

Below I have fixed these mistakes and cleaned up the code.

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
odd_num=[]
count_odd=0
for num in num_list:
    if count_odd == 5:
        break
    elif num%2!=0:
        odd_num.append(num)
        count_odd+=1 
print(sum(odd_num))
```

output

```
993
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it required for you to use a `while` loop? Otherwise a simple solution would be to add a `if` condition inside your for loop for example

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
result=0

odd_num=[]

count_odd=0


for i in range(len(num_list)):
  if count_odd < 5:
    if num_list[i]%2!=0:
      print(num_list[i])
      odd_num.append(num_list[i])

      count_odd+=1 

      result+=sum(odd_num)
print(result)
```

What is happening in your while loop is that your while loop runs, it runs 5 times, meaning your for loop runs 5 times so essentially the result= 85 + 719 + 85 + 17 + 191 calculation is ran 5 times which is something you dont want. You want to check your count inside your for loop, not have the for loop run 5 times. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It's because the for loop finishes completely each iteration of the while loop even if 5 odds have been found. You could just check the count at the end of each loop.

```
while count_odd < 5:
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        if num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
            odd_num.append(num_list[i])
            count_odd += 1 
            result+=sum(odd_num)
            if count_odd >= 5:
                break
```

Or you could just remove the for loop entirely.

```
i = 0
while count_odd < 5:
    if num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        odd_num.append(num_list[i])
        count_odd += 1 
        result += sum(odd_num)
        print(count_odd)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop, the `while` loop.

```py
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

odd_num=[]

count_odd=0

i = 0

while count_odd < 5:
   print(num_list[i])
   if num_list[i]%2!=0:
      odd_num.append(num_list[i])
      count_odd+=1 
   i += 1

result = sum(odd_num)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate through the list, filter out all the even numbers, use list slicing to select the first 5 odd numbers, then sum them.

```
n = sum(list(filter(None, [i if i%2==1 else None for i in num_list]))[:5])
```

`print(n)` gives:

```
993
```

or 85 + 719 + 85 + 17 + 87 = 993 (the first 5 odd numbers)

Comment: `filter(lambda x: x%2 == 1, num_list)` would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Or `(i for i in num_list if i%2 == 1)`

Comment: You also don't need to convert the `filter` instance to a list first; `sum` can add up arbitrary iterable values.

Comment: still need to draw it in a sum function `sum(list(filter(lambda x: x%2 != 0, num_list))[:5])`

Comment: `TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable` you do need to convert it to a list, how else are you going to use list slicing to select only the first 5 items?

Comment: I don't think OP would be able to understand this.

Comment: Although correct, would be hard for a beginner struggling with `while` loop to understand this

Comment: You can use `islice` to grab the first 5 elements from a `filter`.

Comment: @lyncx I find this far easier to explain than using a while loop. "How do you get rid of the even numbers?" "Use `filter`." "How you get the first 5 elements?" "Use `islice`." "How do you add them up?" "Use `sum`".

Comment: Neither have i said this is not valid or not a good answer? I just said OP would find it hard to understand, when he's just starting out. You guys are confused on what would be the best approach, imagine how hard it would be for him. Yes later down the road this is the optimal solution.